# Substring on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

I'm trying to convert all fragment links to relative ones by removing the leading `#`, but the following will not run:

```
$('a[href^=#]').attr('href', $(this).attr('href').substring(1));
```

If I replace `$(this).attr('href').substring(1)` with `$(this).attr('href')+'test'` or `'test'+'TEST'.substring(1)` it runs. What's wrong with `$(this).attr('href').substring(1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$(this)` does not refer to the `<a>` tag found by your selector, rather the current scope of the code. You need to use the [function overload of attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) instead:

```
$('a[href^=#]').attr('href', function(i, attr) {
    return attr.substring(1);
});
```